# How to move back to the viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios4, uiviewcontroller

There are 3 view controllers `View1,View2` and `View3`.

From `view3` I have to navigate to `view1`.

I have tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
//in View3.m
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
{
    appDelegate.isComingFromCountries = YES;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
//in View2.m
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {
  if (appDelegate.isComingFromCountries == YES)
    {

        appDelegate.isComingFromCountries = NO;
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    }
```

But this code doesn't work. How do I handle this?

Comment: If you are use Nvigation Controller that use   [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: I used this.                                                    CurrentLocationViewController   *obj = [[CurrentLocationViewController alloc] init];
            UINavigationController *navBar=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:obj];
            [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navBar animated:YES];

Comment: [[[self parentViewController] parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  USE THIS MIGHT HELP

Answer (score 2):

You can use use `presentingViewController` for dismissing it,

try this -

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

A -> B -> C

Running the above code in modal C will take you back to A.

Comment: @user2798258: than you can accept the answer, so it may helps to other.

Comment: @Virussmca I have posted one more way to get rid of this problem,but your one is so simple.

Comment: @Virussmca - do u mean that if I have 4 controllers like A->B->C->D, then I should use [self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController.presentingViewController...] to navigate to root?

Comment: Cleaner to use a delegate.

Comment: @NSS: yes if you use 4 controller that you have to use what you said,, i would suggest better to use NavigationController for that,

Comment: if you dont want this, than create recursive function that check its parent and dismis it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use delay method to perform animation so that main thread should start performing in B viewController

`[self performSelector:@selector(methodForDissmiss) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];`

then write dismiss code in selector method  to work by your logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one :
if you are pushing one viewController to another and want to move back then use this one

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

if you are presenting viewController use modelly and want to move back then use this one

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

also you can try this because first you need to dismiss third viewController then second one.

```
UIViewController *viewController = [self parentViewController];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [viewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning to the root view controller from a series of modally presented view controllers then the following code will work in iOS6

```
[self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, It may help you. According to your code( in comments area), You second view controller push from first view controller, then present third from second. So you have to set delegate as second in third. And do your code as below in third VC.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
{
    appDelegate.isComingFromCountries = YES;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self.delegate dismissModal];
    };

}
```

In SecondVC.m

```
-(void)dismissModal
{ 
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can pop to `view 1` from `view 3` on like this:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

   [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
   [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```